# Detecting failure of a Bash "export" value

Tags: bash, scripting

In Bash I'm executing a command and putting the result in a variable like this:

```
export var=`svn ls`
```

But if SVN fails for some reason--say it returns a non-zero error code--export still returns status code 0. How do I detect if the executed command fails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var=`svn ls`
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
        export var
else
        unset var
fi
```

`$?` is the exit code of the last command executed, which is `svn ls` here.

jmohr's solution is short and sweet.  Adapted mildly,

```
var=`svn ls` && export var || unset var
```

would be approximately equivalent to the above (`export` of a valid identifier will never fail, unless you've done something horrible and run out of environment space).  Take whatever you want -- I use `unset` just to avoid `$var` possibly having a value even though it's not exported.

Comment: `if var=$(svn ls); then export var; else unset var; fi` would be a cleaner formulation. No point in checking `$?` -- with the attendant increased fragility, since this means logging or other commands can disrupt that status -- when you can branch directly on the line itself.

Answer (score 4):

```
var=`svn ls` && export var
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, it can be done like this:

```
rm -f error_marker_file
export var=`svn ls || touch error_marker_file`

[ -f error_marker_file ] && echo "error in executing svn ls"
```

Comment: It works. I'll hold out for a slightly more elegant solution--otherwise you've got it.

Answer (score -1):

```
export FOO=$(your-command) || echo "your-command failed"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the question states: $? gets set from "export", not "your-command", if you write it like this.